# Are people in favor of Brexit planning to stop visa free travel for EU citizens?

Tags: united-kingdom, european-union, brexit, schengen-area

In amongst all the news reports about the Brexit campaign I can't find answers to some simple questions. Here is just one.

- Does the Brexit campaign want to end visa free travel to the UK for all or some EU citizens even for leisure travel?

Comment: You may want to clarify which Brexit campaign you mean, while Vote Leave has been selected by the Electoral Commission (which mostly means it's allowed to spend more money and gets a free mailing) there are multiple other groups such as Leave.EU.

Comment: @origimbo I suppose I mean the official campaign which is Vote Leave.

Comment: I suppose impeeding travel like this would have a negative impact on free trade and "friendly cooperation". So it would at least be hyprocratic to bring back visas etc. However, the EU will have a great deal to say about that, even after a Brexit.

Answer (score 2):

In case of exit, it depends on the terms, i.e. if UK joins EEA or if it will enter into a free trade agreement or goes into a new framework. It is not pre-decided. For more info:

[What could Brexit mean for UK travel](http://www.theguardian.com/small-business-network/2016/may/11/what-brexit-uk-travel-tourism-industry-visas)

Comment: That link is mostly guessing by third parties.  Do the Brexiters themselves not have a policy or a wish?

Comment: Judging by their positions in 
[FAQ 14](https://leave.eu/en/faqs)
 and in [PDF slide 11](http://www.voteleavetakecontrol.org/our_case), I think they are going for the free trade agreement. However, it is up to the EU to agree afterwards.

Answer (score -5):

**The exit of the U.K from the EU will means all EU Citizens will no longer have the right to enter the U.K unless the U.K gives them permission - just as the USA does to the rest of the world.**

But it would not be their intention to stop or make it difficult for EU Citizens to come to the U.K.

**We are an Island. We are also the end of the line for those in Europe who have searched for work and found none until they arrived here. We are also a link between crime networks in America Europe and Africa.**

What those who want the U.K to leave the U.K are saying is that many criminals and potential terrorists can come to the U.K and enter without any form of security check.

**If I were Prime-Minister I would seal the borders with some of our 80,000 troops who seem to spend everyday commemorating the sacrifice of those who fought for the freedom and security of the U.K.and search every car etc coming in.**

As far as a U.K not being in the EU I cannot imagine it would be no different to the USA or any other non-EU country - you would simply apply for a on-line visa.

**To me it seems ridiculous to let people into your country that may be criminals on the run or potential  terrorist. The EU despite the billions it has spent still does not have a common EU Criminal database.**

You are right about finding information. Boris Johnson who heads up the exit campaign could not organise a set of traffic lights without an accident.

**On a personal note I am voting to leave because of the EU's record on human rights - mine and the refugges who drown in the Mediterranean.**

Comment: This answer looks like a personal opinion; can you please provide with some references? Any research proving that refusal to participate in collective security is good for UK? For instance, Turkey has *closed* border with Syria, this does not eliminate penetrating terrorists. Also, "searching cars": 80k troops × £50k annual salary would be £4 billion, 7 times (!) more than this year's entire [border security budget](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/2016/04/20/border-security-budget-to-fall-by-2-million-theresa-may-confirms/), £558 million. And no angel (or Angela) would cover that expenses.

Comment: Also, the phrase `those who want the U.K to leave the U.K ` seems to have a typo within.

Comment: Some of this depends strongly on what relationship the UK negotiated post secession. For example, if the UK joined EFTA (which I understand to be the mandated route to remaining in the European Economic Area) then it would either still be required to allow freedom of movement for (and to) EU countries, or force the renegotiation of the EU's treaties with EFTA. Also you should probably note that short stay travel between the US isn't under an online visa, but under a visa waiver (thus technically visa free travel). A full visa requires an interview at an embassy beforehand.

Comment: @origimbo - good points, also it's worth noting that the Swiss, having voted to restrict EU migration may have to reverse that position or risk losing access to the single market.